# Trying to transform HTML table to XML with attributes - pick out headers, and data

Tags: xslt, predicate

I have a simple HTML input file; which contains a table.
The column headers of the HTML table are defined in row 2; and the data follows for row 2+.

So I'm picking up the data like this:

```
<xsl:template match="HTML">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//TABLE/TR[position() > 2]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TR">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="TD"/>
</xsl:template>



   <xsl:template match="TD">
    <xsl:variable name="pos"><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="/HTML//TABLE/TR[2]/TD[$pos]"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

(This last template is a debug version; the final output I'm after is to use the header information to generate dynamic attribute names)

What I'm struggling to get, is the $pos variable to index the TR[2] on the document: it always seems to equate to '1'; originally I just trying using 'position()' and the index, but this doesn't work for me.

I know (if I do an 'xsl:value-of') that $pos is correctly changing, but within the predicate it seems to collapse into a 1 ....

What do I need to do here....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem is here**:

```
/HTML//TABLE/TR[2]/TD[$pos]
```

**In XPath it must be known that `$x` is a number and only then `someElement[$x]` is treated as a shortcut to `someElement[position() = $x]`**

**In XSLT 1.0 / XPath 1.0 there is only rudimentary, weak typing** and the type of a variable cannot be specified and isn't generally known.

**This is why, this XPath expression**:

```
/HTML//TABLE/TR[2]/TD[$pos]
```

**is interpreted as**:

```
/HTML//TABLE/TR[2]/TD[boolean($pos)]
```

and selects all `TD`  elements that are children of the `TR` element that is the second `TR` child of any `TABLE` element that is a descendant of the top element of the XML document.

**Solution**:

**In XPath 1.0 use either the full unabbreviated expression**:

```
/HTML//TABLE/TR[2]/TD[position() = $pos]
```

**or use the shorter**:

```
/HTML//TABLE/TR[2]/TD[number($pos)]
```

**In XPath 2.0 (XSLT 2.0), explicitly specify the type of the variable**:

```
<xsl:variable name="pos" as="xs:integer" select="position()"/>
```

**and then it can be used and correctly known to be an `xs:integer`** in:

```
/HTML//TABLE/TR[2]/TD[$pos]
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it; for some reason I have to cast (coerce?) the $pos with the number function:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/HTML//TABLE/TR[2]/TD[number($pos)]"/>
```

I am still unable to use position() directly in this predicate - presumably because it is not clear which position() I'm talking about ?